# The argument type 'UserModel? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserModel Function(User?)'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web, flutter-streambuilder

Error : I am getting below error in **Stream while mapping**

The argument type 'UserModel? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserModel Function(User?)'
The code and the directories

**-user.dart**

```
class UserModel {
 final String id;
 UserModel({required this.id});
}
```

**-auth.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_login/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

//Create UserModel Object

UserModel? _userFromFireBase(User user){
  // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
  return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
}

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<UserModel> get users{
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFireBase);
  }

  //sign-in method
  Future signInAnon() async{
    try{
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFireBase(user!);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you read documentation about null safety in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
UserModel? _userFromFireBase(User user){
  return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

to

```
UserModel? _userFromFireBase(User? user){
  return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

The _userFromFireBase user in your code is nullable yet the User object you are passing in is not. Make it nullable by adding the ? after your User class name like User? user and it will work